# Scrape from a website that requires twitter login with Python

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping

I’ve recently had to perform some python web scraping from a site that required twitter login. It wasn’t very straight forward as I expected and I'm encountring a lot of problems :

I'm trying to **scrape** data from https://www.scoutzen.com/twitter-lists/search?page=1&q=luxury
And I can access to the result only when I'm connected to twitter . So I tried to log in twitter with python and then send the request to website I want .
hereunder my code :

```
session_requests = requests.session()
result = session_requests.get("https://twitter.com/login")


authenticity_token=
list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='authenticity_token']/@value")))[0]


payload = {
    'action': 'login',
'session[username_or_email]': 'mail@gmail.com', 
'session[password]': 'pass', 
'authenticity_token': authenticity_token
}

result = session_requests.post("https://twitter.com/login", data = payload, 
headers = dict(referer = "https://twitter.com/login"))

# Scrape url
result = session_requests.get("https://www.scoutzen.com/twitter-lists/search?
q=luxury", headers = dict(referer = "https://www.scoutzen.com/twitter-
lists/search?q=luxury"))

print(result.text)
```

I checked that the log in twitter was performed with success , but I realized that the website [www.scoutzen.com](http://www.scoutzen.com) still require a login .

Could it be related to cookies ?
Or should I try another package to log in ?

I will appreciate Any help .
Many thanks

Comment: FYI It’s __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraper__, __scraped__) not scrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to deal with this problem is to use Selenium web browser, which can be controlled with python. That way, it will work just as your web browser and will manage all cookies and everything for you. With it you can also display javascript.

Check the [Selenium Starter Guide](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)

Comment: Hi Juan , thank you for this proposition . The problem is that this process is a part of an application I made with python and it should be used by many users . It was working perfectly until the website start requiring a login and a password .

Comment: Not sure what the inconvenience would be, Selenium is a browser for python, you shouldn't have problems using it.

Comment: I have just tried Selenium , the functionning is amazing . It worked perfectly when I started sending requests but it seems that the website banned me after multiple login . Certainly , they do not allow automatic log in .... Did you encounter this problem before ? Many Thanks

Comment: yes, there are many ways to avoid it. Maybe have a look at this service, but it is not free https://scrapinghub.com/crawlera

Comment: Ah ok , thanks . But have you tried to use a proxy within selenium ?

Comment: Is it possible to do scraping past a /login while the /login is disallowed in the robots.txt?